# xmlserialization without managed code?

Tags: c++, xml, xml-serialization, command-line-interface, managed

Is there a possibility to use xmlwriter (xmlserialization) without managed code (cli)?

```
using namespace System::Xml;
using namespace System::Xml::Schema;
using namespace System::Xml::Serialization;
```

My XML serialization managed code:

```
void TXML_Interface::LoadXML( String^ filename )
{
XmlSerializer^ serializer = gcnew XmlSerializer( TTEST::typeid );

FileStream^ fs = gcnew FileStream( filename,FileMode::Open );
XmlReader^ reader = gcnew XmlTextReader( fs );

m_test = dynamic_cast<TTEST^>(serializer->Deserialize( reader ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes it is possible to do XML maniuplation (including serialisation) without managed code - I'd normally do this using [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742.aspx) however there are various ways to perform xml serialisation in C++ (I'm not really a C++ person but Google is almost certainly the first place to look).

However this is using a different mechanism from the ones contained in the `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace.  Unfortunately for you the Xml serialisation in .Net is all implemented in managed code, and so if you want to use it you will need to call into managed code (e.g. by using the `/clr` compiler option or COM interop).

Comment: Thanks for your response! The problem is, that c++ cli (managed code), as you described in your post, does not support IntelliSense which would be helpful for further implementation. Is there a possibility using IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2010 C++ when using /clr (managed code)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) libary is what you are looking for.

Serialization capabilities are rather limited in C++ so [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) is more like a framework that enable you to make your own classes serializable.